# Draw over another app?

Tags: android

I am wanting to be able to start an activity of my app from anywhere in Android. I am wanting to do this by overlaying a button over any apps that are open.

How would I go about doing this, if it is possible.

Comment: Even if you could, this is a really bad idea.  How would you stop your button overlaying a key part of the other apps UI?

Comment: @roviuser no it wouldn't. I have seen another app do something similar.

Comment: @Simon by making sure I only start the activity that shows the button when a specific app is open.

Comment: OK, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, without root or any modifications to the system, as Facebook clearly show with Chat Heads.

All you need is a special permission `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` that lets you add windows with type `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` that are displayed above other apps. Then, with some intimate knowledge of `WindowManager`, you can do practically anything you want.

It would be pretty difficult to do this for a specific app but probably not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can do this. There's "Stand-Out" library available in GitHub. You can check it here - https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut

And this works super fine without root permission.